# How to check if table is empty using cakephp and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

how do we check if table is empty with cakephp and ajax? In my **index.ctp** I have an image that when clicked, it will inform the user if the table is empty or not. If it's empty, an alert box will appear, and if it's not, it will be redirected to another page.

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->image('movie.png', array('onclick'=>'check()'));
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function check(){
//check browser comp, create an object
object.GET("GET", url, false);
//rest of the code here
}
```

**MoviesController.php**

```
function index(){
  //something here
  $moviecount=$this->Movies->find('count');
  $this->set('moviecount', $moviecount);
}
```

I know how to do it using the normal `PHP` coding, but with `cakephp`, and since I am new, I dont know yet. For regular `PHP` coding,  I used the `GET` method for `AJAX`, and I can specify the URL for the `PHP` query inside the `GET` function. I don't know how to do it using cake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the layout to AJAX then render your view. I strongly recommend not to use the `index()` method for this. Instead you can define a `whatever()` method in the `MoviesController`:

```
function whatever(){
    //It is not a bad idea to do this only for GET - use the RequestHandlerComponent
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $moviecount=$this->Movies->find('count');
    $this->set('moviecount', $moviecount);
}
```

The in the view file `whatever.ctp`:

```
echo json_encode(array('moviecount' = $moviecount));
//It is a good idea to add an isset() ternary check here like:
// echo isset($moviecount) ? json_encode(array('moviecount' => $moviecount)) : json_encode(false);
```

Notice that I am creating an array and encoding it to JSON. This is the way to convert variables to and from JSON. To decode use `json_decode()` of course.

The Client-side code really depends on what you're using to make the AJAX call but let us say that the call succeeded and you got the data back in the `data` variable:

```
//Make the AJAX call to example.com/movies/whatever via GET
//Check what data is but it should definitely be an array
if (data['moviecount']) {
    //If moviecount is 0 it will go in the else statement - 0 i falsey
    window.location = 'example.com/redirect/url';
} else {
    alert('No records');
}
```

I advice against using `alert()` to inform the user that there are no records. Better put it somewhere in the page - in some div or whatever. Since this is an AJAX request it could be repeated many times. Consecutive use of `alert()` is not really user-friendly in this case.

Comment: yeah but $this->layout = 'ajax'; messed up my view.ctp.

Comment: Well create the layout file... The layout cannot mess up your view file. Stop expecting people here to answer every noob question you're asking.
You would have easily solved this on your own if you had searched and read a bit. This question has been answered several times here. This is all explained very well in the CakeBook.